# How to change the CurvedAnimation in Flutter on controller reverse?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

When an Animation controller is set `forward()`, I want the Animation attached to it to have a  `CurvedAnimation` of `Curves.elasticIn`

When an Animation controller is set `reverse()`, I want the Animation attached to it to have a  `CurvedAnimation` of `Curves.elasticOut`

I thought of changing the Curve just before the animation but it does not change it.

This is my attempt:

```
   if (!pinDropAnimationController.isAnimating) {
          if (mapController.isCameraMoving) {
            pinDropAnimationTween.animate(
                new CurvedAnimation(
                    parent: pinDropAnimationController, curve: Curves.linear));
            pinDropAnimationController.forward();
          } else {
            pinDropAnimationTween.animate(
                new CurvedAnimation(
                    parent: pinDropAnimationController, curve: Curves.elasticIn));
            pinDropAnimationController.reverse();
          }
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

On the CurvedAnimation constructor you have an argument named reverseCurve !

It does the job really well :)

Comment: provide with an example